# C++ template class operators overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

recently I have been working on matrix class, everything went fine until I tried to implement `+`operator. I just can't figure out why it is not working. I have looked at many GitHub pages to see how other people implemented it but still couldn't find any problems in my code.

My class looks like this:

```
template<class type = int>
    class matrix{
    private:
        int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
        int ROWS, COLS;
        type* array;
}
```

Constructor:

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>::matrix() : WIDTH(0), HEIGHT(0), ROWS(0), COLS(0), array(nullptr) {}
```

Copy constructor:

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>::matrix(const matrix& matrixObj) : WIDTH(matrixObj.WIDTH), COLS(matrixObj.WIDTH), HEIGHT(matrixObj.HEIGHT), ROWS(matrixObj.HEIGHT), array(matrixObj.array){}
```

Destructor:

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>::~matrix(){
    WIDTH = COLS = 0;
    HEIGHT = ROWS = 0;
    delete[] array;
}
```

`=` operator

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>& matrix<type>::operator=(matrix matObj) noexcept {
    swap(*this, matObj);
    return *this;
}
```

`+=` operator

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>& matrix<type>::operator+=(const matrix& matObj) {
    if (matObj.WIDTH != this->WIDTH || matObj.HEIGHT != this->HEIGHT)
        throw std::runtime_error("Both matrices must have same dimensions!");

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++)
        array[i] += matObj.array[i];
    return *this;
}
```

`+` operator

```
template<typename type>
matrix<type> operator+(matrix<type> lhs, matrix<type>& rhs){
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

When I try to run below code:

```
matrix<int> mat1(2, 3), mat3(2, 5), mat2;
mat2 = mat1 + mat3;
```

It returns some random garbage value for `mat1` and `mat2`.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I have implemented overloaded constructor which looks like this:

```
template<class type>
matrix<type>::matrix(int size, type values = 0) : WIDTH(size), HEIGHT(size), ROWS(size), COLS(size) {
    int iter = size * size;
    delete[] array;
    this->array = new type[iter];
    while (iter--)
        array[iter] = values;
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor is broken: `array(matrixObj.array)` – so the two matrix instances will share the same array, and both will try to delete it, resulting in undefined behaviour. You'll have to make a deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

You don't initialise array anywhere to anything other than `nullptr` so any use of `array` causes undefined behaviour.

Your copy constructor needs to copy the array rather than just copying the pointer.

The simplest fix to all this is to just use a `std::vector`:

```
template<class type = int>
    class matrix{
    public:
        matrix() : WIDTH(0), HEIGHT(0), ROWS(0), COLS(0) {}
    private:
        int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
        int ROWS, COLS;
        std::vector<type> array;
};
```

The above doesn't require a copy constructor, assignment operator or destructor as the compiler generated defaults do the right thing.